# mailto body desde php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo este código

```
 <table width=100% border="5" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <tr>
    <th width=12% align="center" scope="col">nombre</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <?php $customers = "select * from x where nombre <> ''";
    while ($customers) {?>
    <th align="center" scope="col"><?php echo $customers['nombre']; ?></th>
    <?php } ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

es una consulta para visualizar en una pantalla, está en php, puedo realizar un `mailto` y el resultado que muestra esta pantalla copiarlo en el `Body`=

Ejemplo:

```
<A HREF="mailto:prueba@prueba.com?Subject=ejemplo&Body=prin%20te%20la%20tabla">Enviar Correo</A>
```

donde el `&Body=` sea el resultado de la consulta antes mencionada?

Necesito que al hacer clic en <kbd>ENVIAR CORREO</kbd> copie en el `body` el resultado de la consulta, no sé si necesito agregar alguna función java o algo que pueda leer php y convertirlo en texto con los espacios utilizando `%20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola deberias almacebar los nombres primero con un while por ejemplo, segun tu codigo seria:

```
$nombres = "";
while($customers){
    $nombres = $nombres . $customers['nombre'];
}
```

Luego

```
<a href="mailto:prueba@prueba.com?Subject=ejemplo&Body="<?php echo $nombres; ?>">Enviar Correo</a>
```

Considera que no podras incluir etiquetas html (para la tabla) ya que con mailto hasta donde recuerdo, su body trabaja con text/plain

Answer (score 1):

Creo que buscas la función `urlencode()` que codifica una cadena de texto como URL.

Entonces usarías algo como esto:

```
<a href="mailto:prueba@prueba.com?Subject=ejemplo&Body="<?php echo $customers['nombre']; ?>">Enviar Correo</a>
```

No he probado el código, pero la idea es esa.

Hay otras funciones que también pueden servirte. Revisa la [**documentación**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php).

Comment: vale he probado la funcion pero en el cuerpo no me printea el texto, en este caso deberia de estar la tabla completa. y no muestra nada.

Comment: Coloca tu tabla en una variable y esa es  la que deberías incluir en el `body`, supongo yo.

Comment: si tal cual lo hice asi &Body="<?php echo $customers['nombre']; ?>"> y no funciono, no copia el nombre